# mapbox studio large shapefile dataset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I have a very large shapefile with 130 columns. I'd like to extract this into 130 layers in mapbox studio.

To do this I have split into three files and uploaded them as tilesets. But as a tileset I can't seem to access the columns.

I see there is a Datasets section as well, dont know if I should be uploading as a dataset instead?

Eseentially I would like to create 130 layers which will show building level data. I am going to use Mapbox GL to show/hide layers to show different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You would upload it as a Mapbox Datasets if you want to be able to edit that data within your Mapbox account, if you don't need to edit it or your happy to edit it externally to Mapbox, go straight to a Tileset.

Instead of splitting it into so many layers, why not just have 1 layer called building, and have all your attributes on that layer. You can then show/hide based on different attributes in Mapbox GL JS using filters as in this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/

It's hard to tell from your question what exact issues you're running into, more detail would help.